# The husband of my father's own sister has passed away. Does this mean me and family gets sutak?

Tags: death

The husband of my father's own sister has passed away. Does this mean me and family gets sutak ? If yes, how long does this sutak last ? According to my father, we only need to leave out tonight's meal and don't do puja in the evening. We can start doing puja at home and  temple from tomorrow. Is this true ? Since tomorrow is Krishna Janmashtami, I was planning to visit the temples and worship the lord. But, I am confused now. What should I do ? If I am under sutak, can I at least worship and pray to the lord from outside the temple without stepping inside it ? Please, help me.

Comment: Duplicate - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16060/rules-regarding-sutaka

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which scriptures mention about Sutak dosha (various prohibitions on child birth)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21381/which-scriptures-mention-about-sutak-dosha-various-prohibitions-on-child-birth)

Comment: Since you’re new, if you’re satisfied with the answer, please press the tick (✔️) button below the voting arrows to accept. It will let other users know if the answer answers the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the definition of Sapinda relation explained [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/43986/20129), the husband of the paternal aunt does not fit in that definition. He is instead categorised as a Yoni sambandha (I.e. your relation to him because of your aunt’s marriage to him)

In the case of death of such a relative, the Kūrma Purāṇa Chapter 32 of Uparivibhāga says:

> In the case of death of Yoni Sambandha (Maternal aunt, Maternal uncle or **Paternal aunt’s families) the ashaucha lasts for a Pakshini (1.5 days)** (see note).
> -*verse 32a*

However a word of caution, the Kūrma Purāṇa advises against eating at their house, touching them and helping in carrying body for cremation. So one may want to avoid these things.

---

<sup>**Note:** The word Pakshini has been explained by Gitapress as:
If the death is in the day time then that day, the following night and the next day till moonrise. If the death is at night, then the impurity shall be from the same night, through the following morning and night, right until the next day begins.</sup>